# Which books contain all of the authentic Hadith?

Tags: hadith

Recently a book was published called "Al-Jami Al-Kamil", it is said that this book contain all of the authentic Sunni Hadith. I also know about a voluminous Shia Hadith book called "Bihar Al-Anwar", but I don't know if this book contain all of the authentic Shia Hadith or not. So, I have two questions:

1: Which Shia books contain all of the authentic Hadith?

2: Which are other Sunni books that contain all of the authentic Hadith?

Answer (score 1):

Several Scholars attempted to compile Sahihs like Bukhari, Muslim, Abu Awannah, Ibn As-Sakan, Ibn Khuzaymah, Ibn Hibban and Al-Hakim and a few scholars attempted to compile all of the Sahih Hadith into single works, from them Diya Ar-Rahman Hindi Madani's Jami Al-Kamil. Other authors who compiled similar works include Muqbil's Sahih Al-Jami and Jami As-Sahih as well as the Mawsu'ah Al-Hadith As-Sahihah by Hamzah Ahmad Az-Zayn.

Answer (score 0):

The book which contain all Authentic Hadith is 'Jami ul Kamil' compiled by Imam Zia ur Rehman Azimi. It contains 16546 hadiths and printed in 12 volumes in Arabic Language. Its English translation is being under progress under supervision of Dr. Zakir Naik (95% completed), and its urdu translation is under progress under supervision of Maulana M. Ibrahim ibn Bashir and Ustad Abdul Rahman Mahdi (almost 50% completed). Its software construction is under progress under supervision of Ustad Abdul Rahman Mahdi.

Links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jami_ul_Kamil
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziya-ur-Rahman_Azmi

Answer (score -1):

Since I am a Sunni I will only be able to offer my point of view.
There are six books of Hadith, Shahi Bukhari being the largest and most commonly used.
This doesn't mean that Bukhari doesn't contain weak (Zaeef, Mozu) hadith. Why does it contain weak hadith? Well so we will not follow it. Shahi Bukhari is associated with Isma Urrijal (Name of Men) which contain the names of all Hadith narrators and biodata.

Bukhari categorize hadith on bases of its narrator, Sahih; Hassan; Zaeef; Mozu. Sahih means all narrators were of sound mind (not too old to have memory issue) and were trustworthy (generally know to be honest and truthful). Hassan means out of the chain of narrators one is either too old that can lead of memory issues or had weaker character. Zaeef and Mozu had multiple weak or bad narrators thus they are not considered when making a decision.

When someone tells you a hadith and you feel it is against Quran or doesn't feel right, ask for "Sanad" (authentication or certification) only follow if it is Sahih or Hassan. You can also confirm if independently.

Comment: All hadith with chains recorded in *Sahih* Bukhari are regarded as Sahih by Bukhari.

Comment: I think you should read and learn before answering such a question! Imam al-Bukhari is a hadith scholar he had his own opinion and methodology on how to categorize a hadith, narrators and narrator chains. As for his book which is known as Sahih al-Bukhari he intended in it to compile only ahadith with a full sanad (narrator chain) that are Sahih according to his conditions. So we can say that any hadith in it with a full sanad is Sahih according to imam al-Bukhari and the conditions of al-Bukahri and those of imam Muslim are the strongest and maybe most severe ones among sunni scholars.